# ASP.NET Core 6, Obtaining Metadata for a custom asp-for TagHelper in the context of an EditorTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

Given an editor for statement in a regular razor view in ASP.NET Core 6.

```
@Html.EditorFor(_ => _.Person.FirstName, "boot-text")
```

The model looks something like this.

```
public class Model 
{
    [DataMember(Name = "firstName", IsRequired = true)]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(250)]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [DisplayName("Given Name")]
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

I have created a custom template. `boot-text.cshtml`

```
<div class="row mb-15px">
    <label asp-for="@Model" class="form-label col-form-label col-md-3"></label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <input asp-for="@Model" type="text" class="form-control mb-5px"
        <span asp-validation-for="@Model"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a tag helper.

```
[HtmlTargetElement("input", TagStructure = TagStructure.Unspecified)]
public class AspForTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-for")] 
    public ModelExpression For { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
       // For is null here
    }
}
```

In the above `TagHelper` the model is always **NULL.**

I looked at the source code here:
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.TagHelpers/src/InputTagHelper.cs

I copied all the source code into my own tag helper, and I also get a reference exception at `For.Metadata`

```
var metadata = For.Metadata;
var modelExplorer = For.ModelExplorer;
```

This begs the question, how does the default tag helper manage to get the model metadata.  The above asp-for renders just fine using my template if I just remove my tag helper altogether.

So the source code I found is perhaps not the real ASPNET Core 6 source code?

Comment: If you don't specify `[HtmlTargetElement("input", Attributes = "asp-for",` your tag helper will run for all `<input` tags.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, you are correct, that is all that was wrong, if you want to add that as the answer I will be happy to tick it. I had all the breakpoints set, but had not imported my tag helper at the EditorTemplate level, so it was running for the wrong tags.

Comment: I also discovered that this works (of coarse).
`placeholder="@(ViewData.ModelMetadata.DisplayName)" `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tag helper will be run based on the content of your `[HtmlTargetElement]` attribute.

When your tag helper is run, your properties will be bound based on any `[HtmlAttributeName]`. But this binding is optional and will not prevent your tag helper from running.

Since you have only specified `[HtmlTargetElement("input"` and haven't included any required `Attributes =` , your tag helper will be run against all `<input` tags even if they have no `asp-for` attribute. Which explains why you are seeing that your `For` property is always `null`.

TLDR: what you need is;

```cs
[HtmlTargetElement("input", Attributes = "asp-for", TagStructure = TagStructure.Unspecified)]
public class AspForTagHelper : TagHelper
{ ... }
```